# Is my implementation of a simple CRUD service with Spring WebFlux correct?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming

I am implementing a simple Movie based CRUD API using Spring WebFlux and Reactive Spring Data MongoDB. I want to make sure that my implementation is correct and that I am properly using Flux and Mono to implement the CRUD operations. I also want to make sure that I am properly handling any errors or null values. I am very new to this programming paradigm and Spring WebFlux, so I am not sure about the correctness of the implementation of the Controller and Service layer, I want to make sure I am adhering to Spring WebFlux and Project Reactor best practices.

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Movie, String> {

    Flux<Movie> findByRating(String rating);
}

public interface MovieService {
    Flux<Movie> list();

    Flux<Movie> findByRating(String rating);

    Mono<Movie> update(String id, MovieRequest movieRequest);

    Mono<Movie> create(Mono<MovieRequest> movieRequest);

    Mono<Movie> read(String id);

    Mono<Movie> delete(String id);
}

@Service
public class MovieServiceImpl implements MovieService {

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @Override
    public Flux<Movie> list(){
        return movieRepository.findAll();
    }


    @Override
    public Flux<Movie> findByRating(final String rating){
        return movieRepository.findByRating(rating);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Movie> update(String id, MovieRequest movieRequest) {

       return movieRepository.findOne(id).map(existingMovie -> {

           if(movieRequest.getDescription() != null){
               existingMovie.setDescription(movieRequest.getDescription());
           }
           if(movieRequest.getRating() != null){
               existingMovie.setRating(movieRequest.getRating());
           }
           if(movieRequest.getTitle() != null) {
               existingMovie.setTitle(movieRequest.getTitle());
           }

           return existingMovie;

       }).then(movieRepository::save);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Movie> create(Mono<MovieRequest> movieRequest) {

        return movieRequest.map(newMovie -> {

            Movie movie = new Movie();

            if(newMovie.getDescription() != null){
                movie.setDescription(newMovie.getDescription());
            }
            if(newMovie.getRating() != null){
                movie.setRating(newMovie.getRating());
            }
            if(newMovie.getTitle() != null) {
                movie.setTitle(newMovie.getTitle());
            }

            return movie;

        }).then(movieRepository::save);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Movie> read(String id) {
        return movieRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Movie> delete(String id) {
        Mono<Movie> movie = movieRepository.findOne(id);
        movieRepository.delete(id);
        return movie;
    }
}

@RestController
public class MovieRestController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieService movieService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/movies")
    public Flux<ResponseEntity<Movie>> list() {

        return movieService.list().map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK));
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/moviesByRating")
    public Flux<ResponseEntity<Movie>> findByRating(
            @RequestParam(value = "rating", required = false) final String rating) {

        return movieService.findByRating(rating)
                .map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK));

    }

    @GetMapping("/movies/{movieId}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Movie>> read(
            @PathVariable("movieId") final String movieId) {

        return movieService.read(movieId)
                .map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/movies/{movieId}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Movie>> delete(
            @PathVariable("movieId") final String movieId) {

        return movieService.delete(movieId)
                .map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK));
    }

    @PutMapping("/movies/{movieId}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Movie>> update(
            @PathVariable("movieId") final String movieId,
            @RequestBody final MovieRequest movieRequest) {

        return movieService.update(movieId, movieRequest)
                .map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK));

    }

    @PostMapping("/movies")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Movie>> create(
            @RequestBody final Mono<MovieRequest> movieRequest) {

        return movieService.create(movieRequest)
                .map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not necessarily an in-depth review, but I see one issue and one improvement:

**The CRUD method for `delete` in your service should combine operators**
Currently you have

```
@Override
public Mono<Movie> delete(String id) {
    Mono<Movie> movie = movieRepository.findOne(id);
    movieRepository.delete(id);
    return movie;
}
```

This is problematic because you return the result of `findOne` rather than the combination of 1) waiting for the DB to find your movie then 2) getting the ack from the DB that it deleted it. The result of `delete` is never subscribed to, which means that it is never actually executed! Even if you added `.subscribe()` there, that could mean you execute both calls in parallel and your controller's response time would be tied to the fetch rather than the delete.

So you need to return a `Mono` that also triggers and represents completion of the delete.

The problem is that delete in the repository returns a `Mono<Void>`. There is a new `Mono.untilOther` operator in the upcoming 3.0.6 release of Reactor that will be usable like this:

```
@Override
public Mono<Movie> delete(String id) {
    return movieRepository.findOne(id)
        .untilOther(movieRepository.delete(id));
}
```

This will trigger the findOne and hold on emitting its value until the delete has completed.

But for now release is 3.0.5 so in the meantime here is a workaround:

```
@Override
public Mono<Movie> delete(String id) {
    return movieRepository.findOne(id)
        .flatMap(oldValue -> 
            movieRepository.delete(id)
                           .then(Mono.just(oldValue))
        )
        .singleOrEmpty();
}
```

The idea here is to first go to the DB to fetch the current value, and one this is done trigger the delete inside a `flatMap`. Once the delete completes (`then(...)`), we're still inside the flatmap and the value from findOne has been captured within the flatmap context, so we can re-emit it using `Mono.just(...)`.

Now because of `flatMap` we are now dealing with a `Flux<Movie>`, but we know it will not contain more than one value ever, so we can revert to a `Mono<Movie>` using `singleOrEmpty`. Note it *could* be empty if the key doesn't exist in DB.

*which leads me to:*

**Some `CrudRepository` methods can return an empty `Mono`/`Flux`**
This you probably want to represent as a 404, especially for the `read` endpoint.
You can use `.defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound())` for that.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is going to take me a while to review your comments, understand them, and make changes.